# Using Spotify authentication with Blazor WASM

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-identity

I want to login an user optional with Spotify (only) as identity provider in asp.net core from an Blazor WASM page.

I use [that example](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET/tree/master/SpotifyAPI.Web.Examples/Example.ASP) to configure the server. I also searched in the Microsoft Docs, but I didn't found an example to start an authentication request. Currently I'm not redirected to Spotify OAuth login page.

I don't know how I start the login flow. Is there a "default" route to start the ASP.NET Core login flow? Or is there any good tutorial to start that?

The Application should have an login button and I need the token on server side and on client side. I would prefer to do the authentication on the server side, because i don't want to have the client secret on the client side.

Are there any best practices to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From you server controller you can call the [ChallengeAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.challengeasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions_ChallengeAsync_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpContext_) method to start the configured authentication schema.

If you are requesting a token from a SPA application (like Blazor WASM), then use Authorization Code With PKCE. PKCE does not require a client secret so it is safe to request if from the client side application.

Otherwise I would use Authorization Code Flow and exchange the code for the token on the server application. Basically the sample you linked does this by utilizing a `AspNet.Security.OAuth.Spotify` nuget packege.
(Spotify uses oauth 2. I would recommend to pick the authentication flow that suits your use case. For example the client secret should not be in any SPA application.)
There is a good summary table on [Spotify docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/).